# How can I do select case to this query?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, inner-join, select-case

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6aef)

I have this structure of tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE Users
    
            ([UserId] int, 
            [IdDepartment] int);
    
    INSERT INTO Users
        ([UserId], [IdDepartment])
    VALUES
        (1, 5),
        (2, 0),
        (3, -1),
        (4, 0),
        (5, -1),
        (6, 0);
    
    CREATE TABLE Department
        ([IdDepartment] int, [Name] varchar(23), [IdUser] int);
        
    INSERT INTO Department
        ([IdDepartment], [Name], [IdUser])
    VALUES
        (1, 'Sales', 3),
        (2, 'Finance', null ),
        (3, 'Accounting' , 5),
        (4, 'IT' ,3),
        (5, 'Secretary',null),
        (6, 'Sport',3);
```

I want to get a query with this results:
In the Users table if the IdDepartment is 0 ist means that the user is an admin so he can see all the departments. If the user has a -1 in the idpartment it means that the user can access to limited departments, so in this case I do a inner join to the Department table to get the list of this departments. The last case is if the user has a number for the idDepartament in the user table diferent to 0 and diferent to -1 it means that the user can access only to this department.

I tried to do something like that, but it is not well structured:

```
select
    case idDepartment
       when  0 then (select Name from Department)
       when -1 then (select Name from Department where IdUser = 3)
       else         (select Name from Department 
                      inner join Users on Department.idDepartment = Users.Department         
                      where Users.UserId = 3)
    end
from 
    Department
where 
    IdUser = 3
```

How can I do this? thanks.

I add an example for what I want to get:

> ```
>  -For the user that has the userid (1) -->
>
>     Department Name
>     ---------------
>     Secretary
>
>
>
>
> -For the user that has the userid (2) -->
>     
>     Department Name
>     ---------------
>     Sales
>     Finance
>     Accounting
>     IT
>     Secretary
>     Sport
>
>
>
>
> -For the user that has the userid (3) -->
>     
>     Department Name
>     ---------------
>     Sales
>     IT
>     Sports
> ```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. You did a great job posting ddl and sample data though. I wish everyone would do such a nice job of that. What would be the expected output of this?

Comment: Can you post the result as well

Comment: This is an small scale example for what I need but I do this example  to know how to handle the select case

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** (like `a+b`) that can return *a single, atomic* result - what do you expect it to return in the case of `when 0` ?? The `(select Name from Department)` will list **all** department's names - and that's **not** a single, atomic value ....

Comment: We need to understand what your requirements are. I applaud your efforts at trying this but your attempt is not going to work. CASE is an expression, it is not used to control flow like this.

Comment: I want to do like an if else code, when the user has for iddepartment a 0 then I want to get all the department names, when the user has for iddepartment a -1 so I want to get a list for this department, and to this I have to do a inner to the department table to get this, because each department has only a responsable person because of that the department table has an userid. And the last case is when the iddepartment in the Users table is a number diferent to 0 an diferent to -1 it means that he has access to only one department.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do but I think you have some problems in your design. You are using a persons department to control their permissions. This is problematic in that you could have people in a department that shouldn't necessarily all have the same permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  declare @IdUser int = 3;
  SELECT u.[UserId], d.Name 
  from Users u
  join Department d
        on   u.[IdDepartment] =  0 
        or ( u.[IdDepartment] = -1 and d.[IdUser]       = u.[UserId] )
        or ( u.[IdDepartment] >  0 and d.[IdDepartment] = u.[IdDepartment] )
   where u.[UserId] = @IdUser 
   order by u.[UserId], d.Name
```

userID 3 should include sport

Comment: Your code works correctly to me also, thanks for your help ;-D

Answer (score 2):

You cant do something like that in a `SELECT CASE`, the best option is to just introduce some logic

```
DECLARE @IdUser INT = 3
DECLARE @userDepartment INT
SELECT @userDepartment = IdDepartment
FROM Users
WHERE UserId = @IdUser

IF @userDepartment = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT Name FROM Department
END
ELSE IF @userDepartment = -1
BEGIN
   SELECT Name FROM Department WHERE IdUser = @IdUser
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT Name FROM Department 
    INNER JOIN Users 
       ON Department.idDepartment = Users.IdDepartment 
    WHERE Users.UserId = @IdUser
END
```

By the way, You've hit upon why your structure is not *ideal*. If you had a junction table between Users & Departments, you could model any combination of what you have already with a much simpler query (At the cost of lots of rows in your junction table)

Answer (score 2):

Your sample code is a bit confusing but feels like you are looking for something like this:

```
declare @id_user int = 3

select d.IdDepartment, d.Name
from Department d
where exists
  (
    select 1
    from Users u
    where u.[UserId] = @id_user
      and u.IdDepartment in (0, d.IdDepartment)
  )
  or d.[IdUser] = @id_user
```

which implements:

- if `IdUser` in `Department` table is the same as `@id_user` given - he has access to this department for sure
- otherwise this user has access to department if his `IdDep` value is `0` or equal to corresponding department ID

But your permissions/security model smells not good and it's absolutely not scalable. You'd better invent another entity (table) to store permitted tuples: (IdUser, IdDepartment). Select statements would look much more clear in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand from your pseudo-query what you're trying to do, you can do it with a carefully constructed WHERE clause:

```
case idDepartment
   when 0 then (select Name from Department)
   when -1 then (select Name from Department where IdUser = 3)
   else (select Name from Department inner join Users on     Department.idDepartment = Users.Department where Users.UserId = 3)
end
```

Could be written as a sub-select:

```
(SELECT Name
 FROM Department
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Users
   on     Department.idDepartment = Users.Department
 WHERE idDepartment=0
 OR (idDepartment = -1 AND idUser = 3)
 OR (Users.UserId = 3)
)
```

You would have to correlate the sub-select to your outer query, of course.